# Overwrite text object with single char

Tags: normal-mode

I'm looking for a way to replace the text

```
print("This is a test")
```

by

```
print("**************")
```

i.e. i want to overwrite every character of a text object (the string inside quotes) or up to a movement command by the same replacement character (asterisk in this case).

What would be the quickest/easiest way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with visual selection and than the `r` command. Like:

```
vi"r*
```

-> Visual select the part within the quotes and replace all chars with a `*`.

For movements I don't know a direct way, but you can do it also via selection:

```
v3wr*
```

-> Visual select three words and replace all selected chars with `*`.

Comment: Thanks so much! I didn't know that ``r`` in visual mode will replace everything selected, cool.

Comment: @fschoenm makes it really easy to create borders: `yypVr-`, for example